# Can you restrict a protocol to a generic type regardless of the type constraint?

Tags: swift, objective-c, generics, subclass

#### TL:DR

How can I make this compile so the protocol can be applied to *any* concrete implementations of BaseObject, *specifically* so it can access `someFuncUnrelatedToTypeConstraint` (that's the real goal)?

```objectivec
@interface BaseObject <__covariant TypeConstraint> : NSObject

- (TestObject*)someFuncUnrelatedToTypeConstraint;

@end
```

```swift
protocol ProtocolOnlyApplicableToBaseObject : BaseObject {}
```

Note: This won't compile because it complains I need to specify the type parameter for `BaseObject`, but that's just it... I want this to apply to any/all `BaseObject<T>` types regardless of what `T` is.

---

#### Now the full code...

In our ObjC codebase, we have a concrete object and a generic defined like so (oversimplified for the example). This says only `NSObject` or one of its subclasses can satisfy the type requirement.

```objectivec
@interface TestObject : NSObject

@end


@interface BaseObject <__covariant TypeConstraint> : NSObject

- (TestObject*)someFuncUnrelatedToTypeConstraint;

@end
```

We also have these (again, oversimplified) ObjC subclasses, the last which omits the type, so it defaults to `NSObject` implicitly.

```objectivec
@interface ConcreteObjectA : BaseObject<UIView>

@end

@interface ConcreteObjectB : BaseObject<UIWindow>

@end

@interface ConcreteObjectC : BaseObject

@end
```

Now we're trying to write a Swift protocol and a paired extension that can only be applied to instances of `BaseObject` because the extension needs to call the function `someFuncUnrelatedToTypeConstraint()`.

```swift
protocol ProtocolForBaseObject : BaseObject {
  associatedtype ReturnType:SomeTypeAcceptingTestObject
}

extension ProtocolForBaseObject {

    func someTest() -> ReturnType {
        let testObject = self.someFuncUnrelatedToTypeConstraint()
        return ReturnType(testObject)
    }
}
```

The goal is so we can call this in Swift...

```swift
extension ConcreteObjectA : ProtocolForBaseObject {
  typealias ReturnType = ReturnTypeA
}
let objA = ConcreteObjectA()
let returnTypeA = objA.someTest()

extension ConcreteObjectB : ProtocolForBaseObject {
  typealias ReturnType = ReturnTypeB
}
let objB = ConcreteObjectB()
let returnTypeB = objB.someTest()

extension ConcreteObjectC : ProtocolForBaseObject {
  typealias ReturnType = ReturnTypeC
}
let objC = ConcreteObjectC()
let returnTypeC = objC.someTest()
```

The issue is `ProtocolForBaseObject` won't compile because it says I have to specify the generic type constraint...

```
Reference to generic type 'BaseObject' requires arguments in <...>
```

But the issue is I don't care what the type constraint for the generic is. I want this to apply to *all* instances of the generic as the function I'm trying to reach doesn't use that type anyway so there's no reason for the protocol to care what that type is.

To get around it, I tried adding `NSObject` as the type constraint, but this doesn't seem to work either since `BaseObject<NSObject> != BaseObject<UIView>` even though `UIView` is a subclass of `NSObject`.

```swift
protocol ProtocolForBaseObject : BaseObject<NSObject> {}
```

So how can you structure the protocol to apply to all concrete instances of the `BaseObject`  generic, regardless of the type constraint?

Comment: hmm a bit confused. Why not just applying the protocol to BaseObject instead of inheriting a protocol of type BaseObject to be applied on its self again later. BaseObject is already inherited from NSObject, so BaseObject<NSObject> makes no sense.

Comment: The issue is I only want that protocol to be available/applicable to objects of type `BaseObject` because the extension to that protocol needs access to something *in* `BaseObject` (specifically the `someFuncUnrelatedToTypeConstraint` method) so if I don't restrict the protocol to `BaseObject` it won't have access to even call `someFuncUnrelatedToTypeConstraint`.  Make sense?  That said, if you can find a way to solve what I just outlined, I'm all for it!

Comment: Also, I think you may have misunderstood what I was saying.  `BaseObject<NSObject>` has nothing to do with `BaseObject` *itself* being an `NSObject`. That's stating the *type constraint* for the generic is of `NSObject` but again, that was just an attempt to solve the issue of the compiler complaining I had to give it some type, even though I don't care what that type is. That's the problem.

Comment: Am I got right, you need make `BaseObject` as abstract class?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the compiler complains because `BaseObject<__covariant TypeConstraint>` requires a type but :

```
protocol ProtocolForBaseObject : BaseObject {
  associatedtype ReturnType:SomeTypeAcceptingTestObject
}
```

A swift protocol can't inherit an Objective-C class

#### Edit (I hate it too)

I would not call that inheritance, and I'm surprised it compiles:

```
@objc class Foo: NSObject {
    let foo: Int
    init(foo: Int) {
        self.foo = foo
    }
}
protocol Bar: Foo {
    
}

class Baz: Bar { // 'Bar' requires that 'Baz' inherit from 'Foo'
    
}
```

does not, the compiler complains about :

> 'Bar' requires that 'Baz' inherit from 'Foo'

It seems the compiler treats `protocol ProtocolForBaseObject : BaseObject` like `protocol ProtocolForBaseObject where Self: BaseObject`

#### Edit Again

```
class Baz: Foo, Bar {
    
}
```

Compiles which makes me say that class `Baz` inherits from `Foo` and conforms to `Bar` but maybe it's just nitpicking

Comment: I'm not sure that statement is correct, as you can easily write a protocol that can only be applied to a `NSObject`. For instance, here's a protocol that can only be applied to `UIView` objects... `protocol ViewStuff : UIView {}` `extension ViewStuff { func testMe(){ print("Success!") } }` `extension UITableView : ViewStuff {}` `let myTableView = UITableView()` `myTableView.testMe()`  (Side-note: I *really* hate that you can't format code in comments! lol!)

Comment: Your comment 'protocol ProtocolForBaseObject : BaseObject like protocol ProtocolForBaseObject where Self: BaseObject' is spot on because *the former is just shorthand for the latter*.

Comment: so that's not inheritance, but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Also, your code makes sense because `Foo` can only be applied to `NSObject` types, thus `Bar` has that same restriction (since it's based on `Foo`), and since `Baz` is *not* a `NSObject`  you can't make it adhere to `Bar`.

Comment: I see you updated your example, so my earlier comment doesn't really apply now, but again, what you're showing is correct and expected.  I'm simply saying in your example if you made `Foo` a generic, how would you structure `Bar` to mean it can be applied to *any* concrete implementation of `Foo`.

Comment: when I read that `The issue is I only want that protocol to be available/applicable to objects of type BaseObject because the extension to that protocol needs access to something in BaseObject` I think protocol with `Self` requirements so `protocol Bar: Foo` should work. I need to try in a project I think

Comment: That's just it... in your example it *does* work, but if you made `Foo` a generic, it wouldn't, telling you you have to provide a type for that generic. I want it to apply to *any/all* concrete types based on that generic.  I don't want to have to specify each and every one.  Make sense?

Comment: Ok I think I understand. `class Foo<T: Numeric>: NSObject` force me to write `protocol Bar: Foo<Int>` right ? But the issue is that the compiler still complains with `'Bar' requires that 'Baz' inherit from 'Foo<Int>'`. And if you want concrete type I think that `BaseObject` should just be a `BaseProtocol`

Comment: I think that's the direction I'm going to go... protocols that specify the methods, then just let the base class satisfy the method requirements.  That way I don't need the base class to be a constraint.

Comment: Yes, the first time I tried to create a module with generics (Swift 4) I tried to rely on inheritance from generic classes. I managed to get something to work but in the end some portions of the code were not mockable and there was too many compiler segfault. 2 problems that were solved when I switched to an approach based on `protocols`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create macro:

```objectivec
@interface _BaseObject <__covariant TypeConstraint> : NSObject
    
@end
```

```objectivec
@protocol _ProtocolOnlyApplicableToBaseObject

@end
```

```objectivec
#define BaseObject(Type) _BaseObject<Type><_ProtocolOnlyApplicableToBaseObject>
```

Usage:

```objectivec
@interface ConcreteObjectA : BaseObject(UIView *)

@end

@interface ConcreteObjectB : BaseObject(UIWindow *)

@end

@interface ConcreteObjectC : BaseObject(id)

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using composition instead of inheritance:

```objectivec
@protocol ProtocolOnlyApplicableToBaseObject
```

```objectivec
@interface BaseObject <__covariant TypeConstraint> : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ProtocolOnlyApplicableToBaseObject> delegate

@end
```

Then your's subclasses will be able to set `self` as delegate or will be able to reuse some other implementation

Comment: thought same. Because then it is possible to check for `[obj conformsToProtocol:(Protocol *)]` which is needed anyway. Specially when handling swift and objC in mix. Fun fact, `conformsToProtocol` and `class` are a methods that can be overridden even if this is not so sexy because of more typing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so apparently I wasn't thinking 'Swifty' enough here.  As outlined in my question, I have been trying to restrict the protocol `ProtocolForBaseObject` to only be applicable to `BaseObject<T>` instances regardless of what T is.  The problem is Swift doesn't let you target a non-typed generic, as shown by the compiler message above.

But then I took a step back and asked myself 'What are you actually trying to solve here?' When I asked that question, it clarified the *real* reason is I needed access to `someFuncUnrelatedToTypeConstraint` from within an extension to the protocol.

Ok, so if you can't do that by restricting the protocol to an untyped generic, is there another way to solve that specific issue?

When I asked that, I'm almost embarrassed to see how obvious the solution was. It was right in front of me all along.

Forget about `BaseObject<T>`.  Just have the protocol define that method as a requirement!

So now, instead of this (which again doesn't compile...)

```
protocol ProtocolForBaseObject : BaseObject { // <-- This line won't compile
  associatedtype ReturnType:SomeTypeAcceptingTestObject
}

extension ProtocolForBaseObject {

    func someTest() -> ReturnType {
        let testObject = self.someFuncUnrelatedToTypeConstraint()
        return ReturnType(testObject)
    }
}
```

I now have this, which works exactly like I had hoped, and definitely is more 'Swifty'.

```
protocol ProtocolForBaseObject {
  associatedtype ReturnType:SomeTypeAcceptingTestObject
  func someFuncUnrelatedToTypeConstraint()
}

extension ProtocolForBaseObject {

    func someTest() -> ReturnType {
        let testObject = self.someFuncUnrelatedToTypeConstraint()
        return ReturnType(testObject)
    }
}
```

Of course there is one slight downside to this approach. While this solves my particular need, that's because I only needed access to that one function.  If however the extension needed access to the entire `BaseClass` object, that may require breaking `BaseObject<T>` into two and moving all non-generic-related methods into `BaseObjectBase`, then making `BaseObject<T>` inherit from that.  Then I *could* restrict the protocol to `BaseObjectBase` since no type constraints are needed.